# Cakephp simple search engine tutorial

Tags: cakephp, search, cakephp-2.0

Does anyone know good tutorial step by step how to create a simple search engine, I just need to add a search feature, which would find similar phrase to content of my database fields. And if it's possible I don't want to use any plugins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > I just need to add a search feature, which would find similar phrase to content of my database fields

If your requirement is that simple then you can just stick to [Model::find()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#retrieving-your-data) and setting conditions according to your needs, for example:

```
$results = $this->Article->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Article.title LIKE' => "%". $text ."%")
))
```

If your search conditions are more complex then you would need to use a more sophisticated solution, i.e. a plugin. I am going to be a little biased here and will recommend [our search plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/search)